# relation between amplitude and frequency of a rotating electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I generated a rotating electric field produced by Ex=cos(wt) Ey=cos(wt-pi/2) in x and y directions. I ran a simulation and seems only in certain amplitudes and frequencies it makes a rotating field. Is there a certain relation between E0(amplitude) and w(frequency) of the rotating field?

Comment: Please post more details of your simulation. What you describe is hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

The field given by components $E_x = \cos(wt)$ and $E_y = \cos(wt-\pi/2) = \sin (wt)$ is always a rotating field, unless $w= 0$, and it will always have amplitude $$
\sqrt{E_x^2 +E_y^2} = \sqrt{\cos^2(wt)+\sin^2(wt)} = 1.
$$

If $w>0$, the field will rotate counterclockwise, whereas if $w < 0$, the field will rotate clockwise. If $w = 0$, the field will remain the constant
$(E_x, E_y) = (1,0)$.

Comment: What if I have both clockwise and anticlockwise moves?

Comment: You can't have the vector $E$ moving both clockwise and anticlockwise. The single components $E_x$, $E_y$ definitely change direction, but the vector $E$ is always either rotating clockwise or anticlockwise.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of two simple harmonic motions at right angles to one another produces what is called a Lissajous figure.

If search for  **Lissajous Figures Simulation** you will find a number of simulators.

Make the x and y frequencies the same and the phase difference 90 degrees and you get your circle produced.

I have not found a good one but here are two which are reasonable.
[Simulation 1](https://ngsir.netfirms.com/j/Eng/lissajous/lissajous_js.htm)
[Simulation 2](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/watch-play/interactive/lissajous-figures-on-an-oscilloscope)

If you find anything better then please publish the link(s).

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any relationship if you do the modeling properly. Could it be that your simulation is not using fine enough time steps to see it? You need multiple steps per rotation - probably at least 20 - to see the rotation. It is possible that your choice of time step and $\omega$ makes it that the field appears to be "frozen" at a particular orientation - in the same way that the wheels of a cartwheel can seem to be frozen in a movie.

In particular, for a given $\omega$ the time step in your model must be smaller than about $\Delta t \lt \frac{20}{2\pi\omega}$. In particular, if your time step is a multiple of $\frac{1}{2\pi\omega}$ there will be no apparent rotation, and for different sizes of time steps you may see either clockwise or counterclockwise rotation (because of something called *aliasing* - also known as the [wagon wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect)).

Comment: I think I have enough time steps because if I set the freq and ampl right it rotates more than 10 times! Actually I want the field to go in one direction (e.g. clockwise) but only in certain amplitudes and frequencies a complete clockwise field, rotating many times is produced. If I dont set them correctly both clockwise and anticlockwise fields are appeared.

Comment: Could you post a few lines of your simulation - it may help figure out what is going on. That frequencies can generate either clockwise or counterclockwise rotation definitely suggests your time steps are too long.

Comment: I don't understand what you are observing.  You should have just one vector,   and it should go clockwise *or* counterclockwise.  It can't go two directions at the same time.  So I don't know what you are looking at when you say  "both clockwise and anticlockwise fields are appeared"